# Convergence in $L^1$ norm, but not point-wise a.e.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, examples-counterexamples, lp-spaces

As part of a course assignment, I'm asked to find a sequence of functions that converges in $L^1(\Omega \subset \mathbb{R})$, yet does not converge point-wise a.e. My thought is that such a sequence would have to be some sort of `sliding function` that moves along, say, $[0,1]$, so that each point has a constant height infinitely often. I've tried to illustrate what I mean below:

[image]

Iteratively, 
[image]

Though, I'm not quite certain if this is the right idea. I can't seem to think of anything else that would behave in this manner, converging to $0$ in integral, but not point-wise. My issue currently, if this is the correct idea, is that I have absolutely no idea how to explicitly write such functions down.

The one's I have depicted would be some sort of shifting of the bump function involving $e^x$, yet I don't know what shifts would be correct, along with what scaling.

Comment: Your idea is fine. You don't need something complicated involving $e^x$. Just a simple characteristic function of an interval will do. E.g. take $f_1,f_2,f_3,f_4,f_5,f_6,f_7,f_8,\ldots$ to be the characteristic functions of $[0,1]$, $[0,1/2]$, $[1/2, 1]$, $[0,1/4]$, $[1/4, 1/2]$, $[1/2, 3/4]$, $[3/4, 1]$, $[0, 1/8]$, ... Hopefully the trend is clear. The first one has integral $1$, the next two have integral $1/2$, the next four have integral $1/4$, etc. For every $x \in [0,1]$ we have $f_n(x) = 1$ and $f_n(x) = 0$ for infinitely many $n$, so there is no pointwise convergence anywhere.

Comment: But of course $\int |f_n - 0|\ dx \to 0$, so we have $L^1$ convergence to the zero function.

Comment: @Bungo Ah. This would make things farrr more simple.

Answer (score 6):

After a little work, I was able to write Bungo's answer explicitly as the sequence of functions $$f_n(x) = \chi_{[\frac{n-2^m}{2^m},\frac{n-2^m+1}{2^m}]}$$ with $m \geq 0$ and $2^m \leq n < 2^{m+1}$.

I'm adding it as an answer for anyone who searches this question in the future, as this may be an easier interpretation for some.

Answer (score 5):

Your idea is perfect; a compact way of writing something that behaves as Bungo's sequence is the following: $$f_n(x) = \chi_{[0,1]}(2^mx - j),\ n = 2^m + j,\ 0 \le j \le 2^m - 1.$$

Here the $m$ is shrinking the length of the interval in which the function is $1$ and the $j$ is responsible for translating this interval.

Comment: +1 Thanks, I was too lazy write a tidy solution/formula, which is why I only commented instead of answering. :-)